# Why is fs.write string not documented in node.js docs?

Tags: node.js

fs.write(fd, str, position, encoding='utf8', [callback])
seems to work just fine, but it's not documented in the File System docs (only the buffer version is).  Does it cause problems if used?

Also, what is the proper fs.open() flag to use with fs write methods that use the position argument?  (By trial and error, I've noticed that 'r+' seems to work the best.)

Finally, does writing to the middle of a file, using the position arg, impose a performance penalty when compared to just appending to the end of a file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> but it's not documented in the File System docs (only the buffer version is). Does it cause problems if used?

It's probably just an oversight. Try submitting an issue or a patch on github.

> Also, what is the proper fs.open() flag to use with fs write methods that use the position argument?

That depends on what you're trying to do exactly.

> Finally, does writing to the middle of a file, using the position arg, impose a performance penalty when compared to just appending to the end of a file?

Node doesn't know about such things, the filesystem in use does. What filesystem are you using? What sort of disks? Are the files on the order of 10's of bytes or 10's of gigabytes? How much are you writing to the middle of the file?

Comment: > That depends on what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: > That depends on what you're trying to do exactly < --
Writing to a text file (utf8) at position n. Using 'w' or 'w+' does not seem to work, and 'a' just adds to the end as you'd expect, so I'm just looking for confirmation that 'r+' is the correct flag.

Comment: > What filesystem are you using? < --
I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. My question is general, but let's say it's a fairly large file, maybe a few Gigs.  If I write a string of 100K to  somewhere in the middle of the file using fs.write(), it will overwrite 100K at that position. But what happens in terms of processing overhead?  Does it point directly to that position on disk, or does it somehow have to stream half the file to get to that position? In other words, is it the same cost to write to the beginning, middle, or end of file, or do these have different costs?

Comment: They have different costs if you're using different filesystems or underlying media, yes, but not to node, just to the time it takes the event to occur. As for the w/w+/r/r+ flags, I am not familiar with that, and looking at http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs indicates no such usage, and https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L154 leads me to believe r+ is readwrite (but you probably just needed to know about that link in general)